# In App Purchase ios - product details not coming

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have tried for in app purchase through last 7 days. I have followed step by step of [Ray Wenderlich's blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) . I have made every necessary changes of the sample code. Though I have 2 products at itunes store for the specific bundle ID, none them displayed on screen or in console window. It returns any empty NSArray. I have also checked "Did n't work " section of the said blog. Did n't work section of ray's blog.

"Didn’t work? If this didn’t work for you, there are a number of things to check (this list courtesy of itsme.manish and abgtan from the forums:

1. Go to Settings\iTunes & App Stores, log out of any account, and try again so you’re sure you’re using a Sandbox account.
2. Check this link – if it doesn’t respond, the iTunes sandbox may be down.
3. Have you enabled In-App Purchases for your App ID?
4. Does your project’s .plist Bundle ID match your App ID?
5. Are you using the full product ID when when making an SKProductRequest?
6. Have you waited several hours since adding your product to iTunes Connect?
7. Are your bank details active on iTunes Connect?
8. Have you tried deleting the app from your device and reinstalling?
9. Tried all that and still stuck? Try the old forum thread or this thread’s comments for discussion with other readers." -- from raywenderlich's blog.

Nothing changed in output.

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

Always an empty array returns to this method's response.products .

I have also gone through [troybrant's blog](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/) and implement that. I found error occurred on fetching of product details from itunes store.

I have also gone through apple's developer site's links.

If anyone have any solution or suggestion please share.

Comment: I assume, everything is set up perfectly from iTunes and source code side. Most probably the chances are, Bank Details. Make sure that All Paid App Contracts and Tax details are filled and not in pending state. If you just filled Bank and Paid App contracts detail before few hours then you may wait for a day and then check again for retriving products.

Comment: Yes. I have mentioned in my question what I did for debugging. iTunes store ok, bank a/c active etc.. One thing is there I have not uploaded  any image for specific product. Is it necessary?

Comment: I filled all those one week ago. After creating all those products, I went for implementation. But till now it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried logging invalidProductIdentifiers?

```
for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
{
    NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
}
```

I'm having the same issue - the server returns invalid product ids, but what is strange, only for some of our apps in the sandbox. What is funny, production version of the same app (with the same in-app purchases) works perfectly. My assumption is that some of Apple's CDN for sandbox is not working properly and we should file a report to Apple's bug reporter.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with "invalidProductIdentifiers". But nothing changed in result. It always returns array with no object.

Comment: Sorry I have done mistake using "invalidProductIdentifiers" code.. It returns invalid product identifiers. But product is perfect.. I agree with your answer. Then there is no option for checking the product purchase before launch? @Szymon

Comment: use only the identifier not com.companyName.appName.productName